# Find radius of convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I have two series:

> (a) $\sum \frac{x^n}{2^n \sqrt{n}}$

and

> (b) $\sum \frac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!}x^n.$

For (a), let $a_n = \frac{1}{2^n \sqrt{n}}$ then $\lim \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right | = 0.$ So the series converges for all real numbers. But how do I proceed for (b)? Can anyone tell me how to find the limit involving factorials?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think the limit in part (a) is correct.  You can check, in fact, that the series diverges for $x = 2$.

Comment: The definition in my book says that $\beta = $ lim sup $(|a_n|)^{\frac{1}{n}$ and the radius of convergence is $R = \frac{1}{\beta}$. The book also says that we can use $\lim \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ instead lim sup $a_n$.

Comment: Do you mean $\beta = \limsup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$?

Comment: You can use the ratio test for the other problem too.

Comment: @tylerc0816 yes!! sorry

Comment: For your limit for a), $\lim \left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right | = \lim \left|\frac{1}{2^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}/ \frac{1}{2^n\sqrt n}\right| = \lim \left|\frac{2^n\sqrt n}{2^{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}\right| = \lim \left|\frac{\sqrt n}{2\sqrt{n+1}} \right|= 1/2$

Comment: To work with dividing factorials just remember how they're defined. For example: $\frac{(n)!}{(n+1)!} = \frac{(1)(2)...(n)}{(1)(2)...(n)(n+1)}= \frac{(1)(2)...(n)}{(1)(2)...(n)}\cdot\frac{1}{n+1}$ Then all the terms from 1...n cancel out so you're left with $\frac{1}{n+1}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do part (a).  Set $a_n = \frac{x^n}{2^n \sqrt{n}}$.  Then $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}} \frac{x}{2} \to \frac{x}{2}$ as $n \to \infty$.  Thus, the series converges absolutely for $|x| < 2$.  We see that the series diverges at $x = 2$ by the $p$-series test.  For $x = -2$, the series converges (not absolutely) by the alternating series test.

Here's a hint for part (b).  Set $a_n = \frac{(n!)^2 x^n}{(2n)!}$.  Then verify that
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{(n+1)^2 x}{(2n+2)(2n+1)}. $$
What happens as $n \to \infty$?  This implies the series converges absolutely for $|x| <$__?

EDIT:
Notice all of the cancellation that occurs.
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \frac{((n+1)!)^2x^{n+1}}{(2(n+1))!} \frac{(2n)!}{x^n (n!)^2} = \frac{(n+1)^2 n! n!}{(2n+2)(2n+1)(2n)!} \frac{(2n)!}{n! n!} x = \frac{(n+1)^2 x}{(2n+2)(2n+1)} $$
Thus, $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \to \frac{x}{4}$ as $n \to \infty$.  Hence, the series converges absolutely for $|x| < 4$.

Comment: If we can ignore the constant as n goes to infinity, then I think the ratio is $\frac{nx}{4} = \infty.$ Can you show some detail how you got the fraction??

Comment: See the edited post.